# C# Winforms App requires two clicks on Button_Click Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, onclick, click

The button requires two clicks to fire up the event. Here is an image and the code.There is a combobox which triggers the button with different items, but when I click the button to show an item in a panel on the page, I have to click it twice so it can trigger the event. After selecting an item once by twice-clicking it, every next time i click it works with one click, just like it should.

[Here is the image of the combobox which triggers the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtlXk.png)

And there is the code :

```
namespace Carbon
{
public partial class ucAnaliza : MetroFramework.Controls.MetroUserControl
{

    static ucAnaliza _instance;

    public static ucAnaliza Instance3
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new ucAnaliza();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel MetroAnaliza
    {
        get { return mPanelAnaliza; }
        set { mPanelAnaliza = value; }
    }

    public ucAnaliza()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ucAnaliza_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void mPotvrdiElementi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((ComboBox)mDropAnaliza).SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "Главна рамка":
                _instance = this;
                ucGlavna uc = new ucGlavna();
                uc.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                mPanelAnaliza.Controls.Add(uc);
                break;

            case "Челна рамка":
                _instance = this;
                ucCelna uc2 = new ucCelna();
                uc2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                mPanelAnaliza.Controls.Add(uc2);
                break;

            case "Подолжна рамка":
                _instance = this;
                ucPodolzna uc3 = new ucPodolzna();
                uc3.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                mPanelAnaliza.Controls.Add(uc3);
                break;
        }
        }
}
```

}

Here is the code from the designer for the button :

```
        // mPotvrdiElementi
        // 
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.CausesValidation = false;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuBar;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Image = global::Carbon.Properties.Resources.Checked_Checkbox_24px;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.ImageSize = 24;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(758, 34);
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Name = "mPotvrdiElementi";
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 25);
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Orange;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.TabIndex = 4;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.TabStop = false;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Text = "Потврди";
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.UseCustomBackColor = true;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.UseCustomForeColor = true;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.UseSelectable = true;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.UseStyleColors = true;
        this.mPotvrdiElementi.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.mPotvrdiElementi_Click);
```

Comment: is there code that removes controls from `mPanelAnaliza` ? because so far it looks that you're only adding more controls to it on each call to `mPotvrdiElementi_Click` , I think it would help if you posted a complete example of the issue, if you can make a smaller version of the project that fits into one file and reproduces the issue...

Comment: Maybe you could replace the image of your control with some of the relevant designer code? Or even a screenshot of the events window for it? That picture is not terribly helpful...

Comment: There is not a code that removes controls from mPanelAnaliza, that is the whole code of that UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a long time ago but I was having the same problem...
But I found a solution to the problem and is working every time and not killing the usability.

```
private int focusFlag = 0;

private void MainForm_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (focusFlag < 1)
     {
         this.FocusMe();
         ++focusFlag;
     }
}
```

This will not always try to focus on that form when trying to go to other forms or something else, it will just focus once and that is enough... after that it will behave normally :)
It seems the MetroForm doesn´t get Focus until you click within the form and it is just a bug from the developers of the MetroFramework when using certain Metro Controls within the Form.

I have seen others posting the same problem when they are using the MetroFramework.

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Since calling FocusMe() once seems to fix it forever, I checked and you can just put FocusMe(); at the end of your MetroForm constructor and the problem goes away.